# Creating Custom SF Symbol

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, sf-symbols

I realise that there is a documentation on Apple, suggest that we can create our own custom SF symbol. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating_custom_symbol_images_for_your_app

I have tried to follow the steps, modified the "Regular M" node. May I know if I need to modify all the node one by one? Or there are some way to automatically generate the other sizes after modifying the "Regular M" node?

Example, the sf symbol "textformat.abc.dottedunderline".
I would like to change the abc to 'efg'.
Is there any automated way to generate all sizes?

Answer (score 2):

You have to modify the SFSymbols one by one, on each size and each symbols. There is no automation for this. I personally use Sketch

Comment: I agree with you, but what I tested showed me with having "Regular M" and "Bold M" we are good to go, as long as we as developer are ok with "Regular M" and "Bold M" the user could not effect our planed font by changing or customising the device. So I think we as developer should modify at least for "Regular M" and "Bold M", and that would cover all possible situation in device but if we got time it would not heart to modify all!

Comment: I got a little bit confused. I follow the documentation and exported a template. I found that there are quite a number of nodes inside. I tried to modify the "Regular M". After that, I noted from your answers that I need to modify the others one by one. Yet, what if I am just satisfying with the Regular M? Is that I can delete the others? What I should do in order to use only the Regular M?

Comment: Like I explained to swiftPunk, the thing is that the other size are used for accessibility. If the user settings are set to bigger of bolder font, the SFSymbols will adapt itself and choose the right size depending on this accessibility settings on the user side. This is why SFSymbols are awesome, so you'd better to modify them all to offer the best user experience. Otherwise, the user will have a big Text for example and a small icon next to it if you only keep the "Regular M" size.

Comment: To come back to our discussion, I created a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Sparklydust/CustomSFSymbols) where we can share our custom SF Symbols. If you want to contribute with yours, it will be worth it in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to automatically generate multiple symbol sizes or weights based on just one.

However, only one style is required: `Regular-M`. As long as you include that one, you can include as many or as few of the others as you like. If Xcode calls for one that you have not included, it will just use `Regular-M` instead.

Any style that you do not wish to include (other than `Regular-M`) you can simply omit from the file.